# What is clang version 10.0.7 for Android NDK?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, clang

I did

```
strings Image | grep -i clang
```

to my Poco M3 kernel extracted from an official ROM for Android 11 and got

```
Linux version 4.19.113-perf-ga223430d113c (builder@m1-xm-ota-bd331.bj.idc.xiaomi.com) (clang version 10.0.7 for Android NDK) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Feb 8 18:34:58 CST 2022 %s version %s (builder@m1-xm-ota-bd331.bj.idc.xiaomi.com) (clang version 10.0.7 for Android NDK) %s Linux version 4.19.113-perf-ga223430d113c (builder@m1-xm-ota-bd331.bj.idc.xiaomi.com) (clang version 10.0.7 for Android NDK) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Feb 8 18:34:58 CST 2022
```

But I don´t  know what is `clang version 10.0.7 for Android NDK)`. I download the 5 latest NDKs and the old ones use clang 9.x.x and then suddenly they jump to clang 11.x.x, without even using the 10.x.x. So, which clang was used to compile this kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it comes from Snapdragon's LLVM compiler https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/snapdragon-llvm-compiler-android

but the version 10.0.7 is not downloadable directly, it looks like you need to use the Qualcomm Package Manager, but it won't install on my ubuntu